# can not refer to the addresses of constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

A constructor is a 'special' member function whose task is to initialize the objects of its class.

it is special because its name is the same as class name. the constructor is invoked whenever
 an
object of its associated class is created.it is called constructor because it constructs the value of data 
members of class.

A constructor is declared and defined as follows:

```
//class with a constructor
class integer
{
    int m,n;
public:
    integer(void); // constructor declared
};

integer::integer(void)// constructor defined
{
    m=0;n=0;
}
```

We can not refer to their addresses but why?

Comment: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/245613/why-doesnt-c-allow-you-to-take-the-address-of-a-constructor

Answer (score 0):

I think in C/C++  we have a concept of pointers to functions and since constructor is a special member function , what they mean is we can not use pointers to functions as in the case of general functions
Hope it may help you

Answer (score -1):

Because the language doesn't allow any way to take the address of a constructor.

Or, if you're asking why it's not allowed: because there's no reason to do so. You'd only take the address of a function in order to call it, and you never call a constructor directly. It's only called indirectly, as a result of creating an object.

Comment: There is a reason to do so: to reflect the structure of vtable(if any) and allow non hostile interoperability between C and C++ where C++ refuses to let C talk to it without forcing creation of new objects(you can't let a c++ function return a local c++ object because it's lifetime is within the function scope, which ends when the function returns), in turn you can't allow C to interface with C++ directly unless you do hard work in memory to figure out this information, that I know C++ knows but it refuses to say it). Abstraction is good, throwing away the ABI is bad.